# Is there anything wrong with this circuit?

Tags: review

I'm hoping for a review of this circuit. I'm looking to make a little IoT device thats powered of a USB mini port or from Vin. There is the MCU, a few sensors, a GPS unit and a RF module.

Any suggestions or comments would be welcome.

[image]

**Updated Schematic**

I think I got most of the suggestions, though the USB lines still need a TSV. I'm just try to read up on it before I add anything.

I did add an EEPROM to this that was not in the previous one.

[image]

Comment: I can't comment on the design, because you haven't shown any connections between the components. It's not feasible to search for every possible connection, _especially_ not in an image without text search.

Comment: @pipe -- he's relying on netnames for connectivity

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem here is a lack of input protection -- at a minimum, you should have:

1. A transient voltage suppressor network for the USB pins, *including* Vbus (you can get a multi-TVS/clamp-diode network designed for USB apps in a small SMT package nowadays)
2. **Reverse polarity protection for Vin!**  Right now, plugging in a negative supply = fried board.  Given the application, ye olde series Schottky (MBRS120 or equivalent) is more than adequate.
3. A transient voltage suppressor for the Vin connection -- I use a bidirectional TVSS upstream of the reverse polarity protection, but you can use a unidirectional device downstream of the reverse polarity protection as well
4. Overcurrent protection on both Vin and Vbus -- a Polyfuse type device can be used for this.

Extra input filtering (such as a common-mode choke or ferrites on Vin) can be deployed if needed/desired, and will improve the board's EMC performance.

Beyond that, you need to specify C6 -- 4.7µF is adequate here, and already on your BOM too.  Furthermore, you are **backpowering your USB port** when you are in a self-powered configuration, which is a **no-no** as it **fries** some USB hosts -- another MBRS120/... Schottky from Vbus to the "+5V" will fix that.  Since you aren't using the +5V line for anything, either, I'd remove C21/C22 and the 5V reg entirely if I were in your shoes.

Last but not least, two more things. First, a resistor divider (say 4.7k over 10k) from Vbus to a port pin is recommended -- this allows for USB host presence detection. Finally, I would put another 4.7µF capacitor on the 3.3V supply to the RF module as RF modules tend to be a bit piggy when transmitting, and you don't want the module browning out itself or other parts of the system during that.

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite broad (EE.SE prefers when questions have more specific questions about specific parts of the circuit), but here are a couple observations:

- C22 and C6 have no value.
- None of your ICs/modules/connectors have reference designators.
- Very little or no bulk decoupling on the 3V3 rail (depending on the value of C6).
- /RST appears to be floating.
- No pullups on SDA/SCL. Maybe one of your devices is a module with onboard pullups, if so, notate as such.
- Can't find anything connected to Vin.
- CS on LPS25H is has an upside-down supply symbol.
- You would do well to add a few more direct connections instead of relying on net names (keep the net names, but add wires on certain things. I2C for example).
- I don't recognize the schematic software package used, but your regulator symbols look awfully sloppy.

Also, [read this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics).

In general, spend a bit of time cleaning up the schematic, and double-check all your datasheets to make sure all pins float the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using upverter, the regulator symbols are sloppy to me as well.